# No Beta badge even with fulfilment of the requirements?

Tags: bug, beta, badges

I have voted more than ten times on the main site, I also have three questions > 0 on the main site, and I've visited the site every day on the main site.

Requirements for the Beta badge:

> Voted 10 times, added 3 posts score > 0, and visited the site on 3 separate days during the private beta.

I have fulfilled all the requirements, yet I don't have the Beta badge.

Why is this the case? (And could I have the badge, seeing as I fulfil the requirements?)

Evidence:
[image]

Comment: I have the beta badge and 60 other people do too. Some people definitely have earned it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not reproducible

Comment: @Starship-OnStrike I disagree that this should be closed. Just because other users didn't run into it doesn't mean there isn't a bug lurking out there. Even if it's not a bug, maybe there's a different criteria that was missed or otherwise not fulfilled that's causing the issue.

Comment: Um...on meta not reproducible is a close reason @Isaiah